# Good example sites using Silverlight and DeepZoom?

Tags: silverlight, deepzoom

I am currently looking into using Silverlight and Deepzoom in a future project. Can anyone suggest some sites that make good use of these technologies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw an amazing demo last week of a site that was about to go live:
[Pre Raphaelite Collection in Deep Zoom](http://www.preraphaelites.org/personal-collections/zoom/37/exceptional-colour/)

Basically it's the entire Pre Raphaelite catalogue of a Museum in the UK - you can browse the collection and then pick images to deepzoom so that you can see the individual brush strokes - is really effective.

[This is the link to the home page](http://www.preraphaelites.org/)

Answer (score 2):

- [Playboy Archive](http://playboy.covertocover.com/) ([NSFW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_safe_for_work))
- [Hardrock Memorabilia](http://memorabilia.hardrock.com/)

Comment: That playboy archive is a really cool example of how other magazines could digitize their archives.  Also, for those of you hesitant to flip through it: Early Playboy is very tame.  You could get 20 pages into the magazines without seeing anything nsfw.

Answer (score 1):

The [Showcase section](http://silverlight.net/Showcase/) of the Microsot Silverlight website has some great demos of Silverlight apps using DeepZoom. Just enter 'DeepZoom' in the search box and it should turn up a number of results.

Here are a few selected from there:

- [Photo Montage](http://www.butterworth.me.uk/clientbin/deepzoom.htm)
- [Bicycle "Configurator"](http://www.faltundklapprad.de/silverlight.aspx)
- [Aerial View](http://app.colaab.com/R/2171fed2-f060-4c2b-b187-9bc10095ec9f)
- [Car Pictures](http://www.laguna-coupe.com/silverlight)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check out shoothill's demos' They have some amazing deep zooms. http://www.shoothill.com

Answer (score 1):

http://www2.advertiser.com.au/uniquelyrundlemall

Christmas Gift Guide site

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Deepzoom, but I know that the kids site [Shidonni](http://www2.shidonni.com/) uses Silverlight quite successfully.

Ori

Answer (score 0):

Two HardRock-'like' DeepZoom collections

- [Melbourne Formula 1](http://www.theage.com.au/interactive/2009/sport/f1/silverlight.html)
- [Mardi Gras (Sydney)](http://www.smh.com.au/interactive/2009/mardigras/silverlight.html)

a business application:

- [Kelley Blue Book](http://www.kbb.com/KBB/PerfectCarFinder/PhotoEdition.aspx) (car finder)

a tagged-photo example with DeepZoom

- [Photos from Bhutan](http://deepzoompublisher.com/ClientBin/DeepZoomMetadataTestPageRC0.html)

and a **GPS**-tagged-photo example with DeepZoom

- [cities around the world](http://conceptdevelopment.net/Silverlight/DeepZoomPublisher04/Default.html) with Virtual Earth ([how-to](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2009/03/silverlight-virtualearth-map-control_23.html))

Answer (score 0):

BestBuy store locator using Virtual Earth post on 
silverenlightenment.com

Answer (score 0):

MGM used Silverlight Deep Zoom and Photosynth to create Stargate Destiny App. You can read about the making of here http://www.microsoft.com/casestudies/Case_Study_Detail.aspx?casestudyid=4000005102 and play with the app at stargate.mgm.com

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the late reply. Here's one I worked on

http://sites.tepapa.govt.nz/tepapawall/